# Interactive R package for real time chart updating of stock prices

Tags: r, charts, real-time, dygraphs, quantmod

Does an Rstudio R package  exist that meets the following requirements?

1) Can chart a timeSeries of 1 minute-based stock data;
2) Is interactive (ie, the user can pan, scroll, zoom, etc) ;
3) Can be automatically updated in realTime

I first tried to find a way to do this with th ever-versatile quantmod package, but no luck.  I am relatively new to R, so there may be a simple way of doing this that I am missing.

There is an R Shiny package called dygraphs that meets some of these criteria, but with that package you cannot specify that the chart only record/display data during market hours. https://github.com/rstudio/dygraphs/issues/70

Does anyone know of such a package?  My R ignorance may be showing here by my failure to understand some  basic R concepts (eg, maybe it is not possible to do anything point/click wise).

Comment: It is definitely possible point/click wise. As you have discovered for interactive plotting part javascript based packages such as dygraps, plottly or googlevis is the way to go.
For real time updating and market hours: you need to set up dashboard in shiny (http://shiny.rstudio.com/) and 1) put condition to check system.time() with market hours; 2) reactive condition to update everytime your input data (minute data) is updated.

Comment: btw, dygraphs is not strictly speaking "Shiny package", it is just "R package" :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Some would consider this question off-topic. 
Please bear in mind that I do not favor or recommend any of the packages mentioned below.
when you say real-time, I presume you're talking minimal lag. quantmod and quandl are mostly meant for historical data. I'm not sure about the Bloomberg (Rbbg- I believe you need access to a terminal or at least an ID) and IBrokers packages. Didn't work for me.

As for your concerns with plotting, did you try annotated charts that come with "googleVis"?

If it helps, you can look at these links:

[related post from stack exchange](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/12670/data-apis-feeds-available-as-packages-in-r)

[list of widely used venues to access Market Data](http://www.thertrader.com/2013/12/13/financial-data-accessible-from-r-part-iv/)

[example on annotated chart](http://www.r-bloggers.com/annotation-charts-and-histograms-with-googlevis/)